# Output text in multiple text-boxes rather than single..tkinter python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-text

```
import tkinter as tk
win = tk.Tk()
win.title('New App')
win.geometry('800x800')


def passgen():
    num = str(inp.get())
# text field for output
    disp = tk.Text(master=win, height=4, width=80, )
    disp.pack()
    disp.insert(tk.END, num)


lab = tk.Label(text='First Label')
lab.pack()
inp = tk.Entry()
inp.pack()
btn = tk.Button(text='Submit', command=passgen)
btn.pack()


win.mainloop()
```

Above is my simple tkinter code but when I run it I get the output in multiple boxes. All I want is each time I use the submit button the output should be in one single box rather than multiple boxes. Is there any way to do it?I am using python 3.
[Screenshot](https://github.com/RK-GIT24/assignment/blob/gh-pages/Screen%20Shot%202020-06-25%20at%2010.33.14%20PM.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is in the way that the `passgen()` method works where it creates a new `tk.Text()` object. to fix this you want to add to the same `Text` object which means creating it outside of the function and then using the global object from the function:

```
...

def passgen():
    global disp
    num = str(inp.get())
    disp.insert(tk.END, num)

disp = tk.Text(master=win, height=4, width=80, )
disp.pack()
...
```